# Submersible pump starter - choosing the right relay

Tags: pump, electric-motor, relay

A few months ago our submersible pump starter stopped working and the local repair shop guy diagnosed it as a relay issue and replaced it.

[image]

While the starter is working fine since then, my concern stems from the relay's Ampere range. As you can see in the image above, it supports the range from 17.4 A to 24 A. Our motor is a 1.5 HP, single phase one. The previous relay's range plate had fallen off and I wasn't exactly aware of its purpose back then though I found it inside the starter that day -

[image]

The supported range mentioned is 8.9 A to 13.5 A in that one.

My understanding after online research is a 1.5 HP, the single-phase motor could draw a maximum current of 10 A, and adding a 20% or so safety factor should mean that a relay should be set at 12 A. In this case, the relay installed at present is absolutely useless in terms of being able to protect our motor.

Is my understanding correct here? Should I replace the relay with a correct rated one?

Comment: I'd replace the entire unit. The cable lugs look too corroded for my liking, and there is no protection against touching the lugs.

Comment: The board that you see is housed inside a box - there is a lid covering the whole of it. The box is in proper shape! I agree there is corrosion - due to prohibitive cost, I have held back from replacing the entire unit.